# Static outbound IP for Azure Web Apps

Tags: web-services, azure, web-applications, proxy, azure-web-app-service

**Is there a 'quick and dirty' way of funnelling calls to a web service via a certain IP address?  Possibly in code (C#)?**

I'm working on this Azure website (PaaS no VM) that's got it's own domain secured by SSL.
e.g. myapp.azurewebsites.net -> https://myapp.com

The system is using a 3rd party web service that uses whitelisted IPs for access control.  Unfortunately they are not happy whitelisting the standard Azure egress IPs.

So what I need to do is find a way to call that web service via our own IP address (the one that came with the domain name package).
If possible, only that traffic, not all outgoing.

I've come across several solutions but I’d rather not want to compromise the stability of the production website by experimenting with App Service Environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the scenario being asked about is outbound calls from an app running on Azure App Service (aka Azure Websites), *to* an external endpoint.

In that scenario, the outbound calls from the web app are NAT'd using a pool of IP addresses allocated for the App Service scale unit that is running your app.

Using the "preview" portal (portal.azure.com), drill into the website blade for your app and click through "All settings" --> "Properties".  In the properties blade that appears, there is a textbox called "OUTBOUND IP ADDRESSES".  Those are the values you need to give to the third party provider to whitelist.

Comment: I'm aware of said pool of IPs. The third party vendor is not keen on whitelisting IPs that aren't exclusive to the system.

Comment: Therein lies the problem!

Comment: So has anyone found a solution to this? I assume there's no way to get a static outbound IP address that's unique to an App Service? Are folks using VMs for anything that requires a trusted IP?